# Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The objects
>   "MstSalesChallanItemDetails" and "MstSalesChallanItemDetails" in the
>   FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to
>   distinguish them.

My statement:

```
Select     MstSalesInvoice.SalesInvoiceDate 
from       MstSalesChallanItemDetails
INNER JOIN MstSalesChallanItemDetails ON  MstSalesInvoiceItemDetails.SalesChallanId = MstSalesChallanItemDetails.SalesChallanId 
INNER JOIN MstSalesInvoiceItemDetails ON  MstSalesInvoice.SalesInvoiceId=MstSalesInvoiceItemDetails.SalesInvoiceId
INNER JOIN MstSalesChallan            ON  MstSalesChallanItemDetails.SalesChallanId = MstSalesChallan.SalesChallanId 
                                      AND MstSalesChallanItemDetails.SalesChallanId = MstSalesChallan.SalesChallanId
WHERE      MstSalesChallan.YearId    = 7 
AND        MstSalesChallan.CompanyId = 1
```

Comment: you have the table `MstSalesChallanItemDetails` twice in the `FROM` clause. Looks like it is probably a mistake

Comment: Or give alias for each table

Comment: `Select t1.SalesInvoiceDate 
from MstSalesInvoice t1
INNER JOIN MstSalesChallanItemDetails t2 ON t2.SalesChallanId = t1.SalesChallanId 
INNER JOIN MstSalesInvoiceItemDetails t3 ON t1.SalesInvoiceId = t3.SalesInvoiceId
INNER JOIN MstSalesChallan t4 ON t2.SalesChallanId = t4.SalesChallanId AND t2.SalesChallanId = t4.SalesChallanId
WHERE  t4.YearId = 7 AND t4.CompanyId = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the table *alias* :

```
SELECT MstInv.SalesInvoiceDate 
FROM MstSalesChallanItemDetails AS MstSal INNER JOIN 
     MstSalesInvoiceItemDetails AS MstInv 
     ON MstInv.SalesInvoiceId = MstSal.SalesInvoiceId INNER JOIN 
     MstSalesChallan MstCh 
     ON MstSal.SalesChallanId = MstCh.SalesChallanId 
WHERE  MstCh.YearId = 7 AND MstCh.CompanyId = 1;
```

Note : You have repeat the same expression multiple times. So, don't need to do this.